# win 32 API how to create toolbar with dropdown menu?

Tags: c++, winapi, toolbar

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <CommCtrl.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "Comctl32.lib")

//1. create toolbar

HWND toolbar = CreateToolbarEx(hwnd, WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | TBSTYLE_TOOLTIPS, 1, 0, NULL, IDB_BITMAP_TOOLBAR, NULL, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, sizeof(TBBUTTON));

//2. set dropdown menu button  

TBBUTTON button = {0};
button.iBitmap = 0;
button.idCommand = ID_TOOLBAR_BUTTON;
button.fsState = TBSTATE_ENABLED;
button.fsStyle = TBSTYLE_DROPDOWN; 
SendMessage(toolbar, TB_ADDBUTTONS, 1, (LPARAM)&button);

//3. create drop down menu item

HWND dropdown = CreatePopupMenu(); 
AppendMenu(dropdown, MF_STRING, ID_MENU_ITEM_1, _T("menuitem1")); 
AppendMenu(dropdown, MF_STRING, ID_MENU_ITEM_2, _T("menuitem2"));

//4. Associate a drop-down menu or drop-down list box with a button.

TBBUTTONINFO buttonInfo = {0}; 
buttonInfo.cbSize = sizeof(TBBUTTONINFO);
buttonInfo.dwMask = TBIF_STYLE | TBIF_COMMAND | TBIF_LPARAM;
SendMessage(toolbar, TB_GETBUTTONINFO, ID_TOOLBAR_BUTTON, (LPARAM)&buttonInfo); 

buttonInfo.fsStyle = TBSTYLE_DROPDOWNBUTTON;
buttonInfo.dwData = (LPARAM)dropdown; 
SendMessage(toolbar, TB_SETBUTTONINFO, ID_TOOLBAR_BUTTON, (LPARAM)&buttonInfo);
```

I created a toolbar button, but the dropdown menu arrow is not displayed, and the button is still disabled.

Comment: Code-only questions are generally low-quality and unlikely to be of use to anyone in the future. I recommend reading [ask].

Comment: `TBSTYLE_DROPDOWNBUTTON` is not a [documented style](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/toolbar-control-and-button-styles). Use `TBSTYLE_DROPDOWN` or `TNS_WHOLEDROPDOWN`. If you use `TBSTYLE_DROPDOWN`, make sure the Toolbar has the `TBSTYLE_EX_DRAWDDARROWS` style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create A drop-down button, specify the `BTNS_DROPDOWN` style (also called `TBSTYLE_DROPDOWN` for compatibility with previous versions of the common controls). To show a drop-down button with an arrow, you must also set the `TBSTYLE_EX_DRAWDDARROWS` toolbar style by sending a `TB_SETEXTENDEDSTYLE` message.

For more details, I suggest you could refer to the Docs:

[How to Handle Drop-down Buttons](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/handle-drop-down-buttons)

[Using Toolbar Controls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/using-toolbar-controls)